# migrating to agensgraph create foreign table error

Tags: postgresql, agens-graph

So, I'm taking a first look at migrating a PostgreSQL db to agensgraph db.
I'm using the manual https://bitnine.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/AgensGraph_Quick_Guide.pdf

first export as csv:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'utf8';
\COPY samples.samples TO 
'C:\Users\garyn\Documents\graph_migration\pg_csv\samples_samples.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER E'\t' CSV;
```

And on page 20 I follow the first steps, creating the foreign table:

```
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER import_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw; 
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE vlabel_profile ( id graphid, properties text) SERVER import_server 
OPTIONS( FORMAT 'csv', HEADER 'false', 
FILENAME 'C:\Users\garyn\Documents\graph_migration\pg_csv\samples_samples.csv', 
delimiter E'\t');
```

ERROR:  cannot create table in graph schema
SQL state: XX000

Now, I haven't set any column names (as header=false) and I haven't changed the `id graphid, properties text` since the manual says it is setting up the table, but it states the file directory, any ideas how to get past this error? I'm back to being a noob.

The next steps will be:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE elabel_profile ( id graphid, start graphid, "end" graphid, properties text) SERVER import_server OPTIONS( FORMAT 'csv', HEADER 'false', FILENAME '/path/file.csv', delimiter E'\t');
```

Then execute the import

```
CREATE VLABEL test_vlabel; LOAD FROM vlabel_profile AS profile_name CREATE (a:test_vlabel =row_to_json(profile_name)::jsonb);

CREATE ELABEL test_elabel; LOAD FROM elabel_profile AS profile_name MATCH (a:test_vlabel), (b:test_vlabel) WHERE (a).id::graphid = (profile_name).start AND (b).id::graphid = (profile_name).end CREATE (a)-[:test_elabel]->(b);
```

------------ UPDATE ------------

I'm now trying with the northwind dataset, again following the agens tutorial: https://bitnine.net/tutorial/english-tutorial.html

```
DROP GRAPH northwind CASCADE;
CREATE GRAPH northwind;
SET graph_path = northwind;
DROP SERVER northwind;
CREATE SERVER northwind FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE categories (
CategoryID int,
CategoryName varchar(15),
Description text,
Picture bytea
) 
SERVER northwind
OPTIONS (FORMAT 'csv', HEADER 'true', FILENAME 'D:\northwind\categories.csv', delimiter ',', quote '"', null '');
```

Same error

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create a foreign table with northwind dataset you mentioned but it works just fine for me as you see the below screen shot.

I installed the agensgraph and tried the sample with its latest version which is 2.1.0 since I didn't have agensgraph on my window OS.

[image]

If you let me know the version of agensgraph you are currently using and how you are accessing to agensgraph, I would be able to help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

re: cannot create table in graph schema
This is an error you will get when your schema is the same as the name of a graph - or there is some other problem related to the default schema.

The default schema is called public. To check your current schema enter

```
select current_schema();
```

If it's not public you can set it with

```
set schema public;
```

then try to create a table

```
create table mytable(id int);
```